# Set cookie with php and do action with javascript (hide) at same page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

What i want: when semeone visit my page with 'page21' in referer set a cookie. If this cookie is already there or if is now set i want to hide specific class (.hide_phone)

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_COOKIE["Numar"]))
{
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
$referer=$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];      
if (strpos($referer,'page21') !== false) {
    setcookie("Numar","1", time()+3600*24, "/", "mywebsite.com");
}}} 
?>

<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["Numar"])) :?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.hide_phone').hide();
 });
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Why this is not working? I set cookie but after one refresh javascript start work and hide that class. I want to do this in one page load.

1. If i put this code in header, it work only on first page that visitator came from. Why is not working in other page if cookie exist. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "do this in one page load" since cookies sent by `setcookie` only can be accessed on the next page load. See [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

**Update:**

Although you cannot do such thing on server side, you can read written value of cookie on client side by [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.cookie) (in plain JS) or by jquery.cookie plugin

Comment: What about doing it using aJAX

Comment: Thanks. So how can i setcookie and use it at same page load ?

Comment: @dragosbd Maybe you meant "how to .."?

Comment: First problem, solved. I put an $static="1"; when i create cookie, and when check if cookie exist i put || static==1; it work. But still remain this problem: it work only on first page that visitator came from. Why is not working in other page if cookie exist.